# Pytorch: Calculating running time on GPU and CPU of a for loop

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am really new to pytorch. And I got really confused the whole day while I was trying out to figure out why my nn runs slower on GPU than CPU. I do not understand when I calculated the running time using time.time(), the time of the whole loop is a lot different with the sum of every single running time. Here is part of my code. Could anybody help me? Appreciate it!

```
    time_out = 0
    time_in = 0

    for epoch in tqdm(range(self.n_epoch)):

        running_loss = 0
        running_error = 0
        running_acc = 0

        if self.cuda:
            torch.cuda.synchronize()                #time_out_start
        epst1 = time.time()


        for step, (batch_x, batch_y) in enumerate(self.normal_loader):

            if self.cuda:
                torch.cuda.synchronize()                        #time_in_start
            t1 = time.time()

            batch_x, batch_y = batch_x.to(self.device), batch_y.to(self.device)

            b_x = Variable(batch_x)
            b_y = Variable(batch_y)
            
            pred_y = self.model(b_x)
            #print (pred_y)
            
            loss = self.criterion(pred_y, b_y)

            error = mae(pred_y.detach().cpu().numpy(),b_y.detach().cpu().numpy())
            acc = r2(b_y.detach().cpu().numpy(),pred_y.detach().cpu().numpy())

            #print (loss)
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()

            running_acc += acc
            running_loss += loss.item()
            running_error += error

            if self.cuda:
                torch.cuda.synchronize()                        #time_in_end
            t6 = time.time()

            time_in += t6-t1

        if self.cuda:
            torch.cuda.synchronize()                    #time_out_end         
        eped1 = time.time()

        time_out += eped1-epst1

    print ('loop time(out)',time_out)
    print ('loop time(in)',time_in)
```

The result is:
CPU:
EPOCH 10: out: 1.283s in: 0.695s
EPOCH 50: out: 6.43s  in: 3.288s
EPOCH 100: out:12.646s  in:6.386s
GPU:
EPOCH 10: out: 3.92s  in: 1.471s
EPOCH 50: out: 9.35s  in:3.04s
EPOCH 100: out: 18.418s  in:5.655

I understand that transferring data from cpu to gpu cost some time. So as the epochs go up, the calculation time of GPU should become less than CPU time. My question is:

1. why the time I record outside of the loop is so different from the inside one? Is there any step that I missed to record the running time?
2. And why GPU costs more outside-time even the inside-time has been less than the CPU time?

The Network is really simple, which is:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,n_input,n_nodes1,n_nodes2):
    super(Model, self).__init__()

    self.n_input = n_input
    self.n_nodes1 = n_nodes1
    self.n_nodes2 = n_nodes2

    self.l1 = nn.Linear(self.n_input, self.n_nodes1)
    self.l2 = nn.Linear(self.n_nodes1, self.n_nodes2)
    self.l3 = nn.Linear(self.n_nodes2, 1)

def forward(self,x):

    h1 = F.relu(self.l1(x))
    h2 = F.relu(self.l2(h1))
    h = self.l3(h2)

    return h
```

the training data is formed as:(regression problem, input_x are descriptors and y is the target value)

```
def load_train_normal(self,x,y,batch_size = 100):       
    if batch_size:
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    
    self.x_train_n, self.y_train_n = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x).float()), Variable(torch.from_numpy(y).float())
    
    #x, y = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x).float()), Variable(torch.from_numpy(y).float())
    self.dataset = Data.TensorDataset(self.x_train_n,self.y_train_n)
    self.normal_loader = Data.DataLoader(
                        dataset = self.dataset,
                        batch_size = self.batch_size,
                        shuffle = True, num_workers=2,)
```

Comment: Better give a complete example for us to reproduce the problem. Running time can sometimes depend on the size of your data, which is not reflected in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> why the time I record outside of the loop is so different with the inside one? Is there any step that I missed to record the running time?

`self.normal_loader` is not just a plain dictionary, vector or something as simple as that. Iterating over it takes a significant amount of time.

> And why GPU costs more outside-time even the inside-time has been less than the CPU time?

`torch.cuda.synchronize()` is a heavy operation. Even when it didn't even do anything useful such as in this case, as `pred_y.detach().cpu()` had already enforced synchronization.

---

As to how to get they faster? Drop the `synchronize()` calls, they don't do you any good.

And then *defer* the processing of `pred_y` until later. Much later. You want to have called the model at least 2 or 3 times before you trigger the first download of results. The simpler the model and the smaller the data, the more iterations you have to wait.

Because transfers to and from the GPU don't just "take time", they imply synchronization. Without synchronization, the execution model on the GPU mostly "lags behind", with data uploads to the GPU already being asynchronous behind the scenes, and actual execution only being queued behind them. If you don't synchronize by accident or explicitly, workloads start to overlap, stuff (uploads, execution, CPU work) starts running in parallel. Your effective execution time approaches `max(upload, download, GPU execution, CPU execution)`.

If you synchronize, there are no tasks to overlap, and no batches to form from same-typed tasks. Upload, execution, download, CPU part, it all happens sequentially. Your execution time ends up `upload + download + GPU execution + CPU execution`. Some additional overhead for breaking batching on the driver level on top. So easily 5-10x slower than it should be.

Comment: Hi Ext3h, Thanks for your excellent explanation. I have figured it out. Thanks a lot!